# In C program, I am having trouble tracing a code that produces roman numerals from 1 to 1000 using loops?

Tags: c, loops, math, char, trace

I am trying to trace a C program that converts integer numbers to char roman numerals from 1 to 1000. I don't understand how this code is converting every single number to a roman numeral. I think romanNum[i++] increments and temp values are doing the math but I am unsure about how. I was only able to trace the range of loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num;
    for (num = 1; num <= 1000 ; ++num) //1000 loop
    {
        int temp = num; //store single values
        char romanNum[1000]; 
        int i = 0; //to increment romanNum[i] //inside because it's getting increment inside the loop
        int j; //for looping separate values
        //1000=M, 500=D, 100=C, 50=L, 10=X, 5=V, 1=I
        while(temp>0) 
        {       
            if(temp>= 1000)//1000 (highest number)=M
            {  
                for(j=0;j<(temp/1000);j++) //0<1 
                romanNum[i++] = 'M'; //1000=M               
            temp = temp - (temp/1000) * 1000; //0
            }
            else if(temp >=500)//999..500
            {   
                if(temp < (500 + 4 * 100))//500..899
                {                   
                    for(j=0;j<(temp/500);j++)
                    romanNum[i++] = 'D';//
                temp = temp - (temp/500) * 500; //0         
                }
                else//900..999
                { 
                    romanNum[i++] = 'C'; 
                    romanNum[i++] = 'M'; 
                temp = temp - (1000-100);  //0
                }
            }
            else if(temp>=100) //499..100
            {   
                if(temp < (100 + 3 * 100))//100..399
                {
                    for(j=0;j<(temp/100);j++)
                    romanNum[i++] = 'C'; //
                temp = temp - (temp/100) * 100;
                }
                else //400..499
                {   
                    romanNum[i++] = 'L';
                    romanNum[i++] = 'D';
                temp = temp - (500-100);
                }
            }
            else if(temp >=50) //99..50
            {
                if(temp < (50 + 4 * 10))//50..89
                {
                    for(j=0;j<(temp/50);j++)
                    romanNum[i++] = 'L';
                temp = temp - (temp/50) * 50;
                }
                else //90..99
                {
                    romanNum[i++] = 'X';
                    romanNum[i++] = 'C';
                temp = temp - (100-10);
                }
            }
            else if(temp >=10)//49..10
            {
                if(temp < (10 + 3 * 10))//10..39
                {
                    for(j=0;j<(temp/10);j++)
                    romanNum[i++] = 'X';
                temp = temp - (temp/10) * 10;//0
                }
                else//40..49
                {
                    romanNum[i++] = 'X';
                    romanNum[i++] = 'L';
                temp = temp - (50-10);
                }
            }
            else if(temp >=5)//9..5
            {
                if(temp < (5 + 4 * 1))//5..8
                {
                    for(j=0;j<(temp/5);j++)
                    romanNum[i++] = 'V';
                temp = temp - (temp/5) * 5;//0
                }
                else//9
                {
                    romanNum[i++] = 'I';
                    romanNum[i++] = 'X';
                temp = temp - (10-1);//0
                }
            }
            else if(temp >=1)//4..1
            {
                if(temp < 4)//1..3
                {               
                    for(j=0;j<(temp/1);j++)
                    romanNum[i++] = 'I';
                temp = temp - (temp/1) * 1;
                }
                else//4
                {   
                    romanNum[i++] = 'I';
                    romanNum[i++] = 'V';
                temp = temp - (5-1);//0
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d ", num);//1..1000

        for(j=0;j<i;j++)//to print romanNum
        {
            printf("%c",romanNum[j]);//I..M
        }
        printf("\n");
    }//end of 1000 loop

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `romanNum[i++] = 'M';` is writing the Roman numeral `'M'` into the array at the currrent index `romanNum[i]` and then incrementing the index `i` ready for the next Roman numeral. The program is like a "change calculator" but more compilated because of the way a Roman number is constructed.

Comment: @WeatherVane how though? the other numbers have a composition of different roman numerals with different values. For example, 999 is CMXCIX.

Comment: @Su.she You do know how to read Roman numbers? Or is that part of the question?

Comment: `romanNum[i++] = 'M';` is the same as `romanNum[i] = 'M'; i = i + 1;` So it saves the character M in the array at index `i` and then increments `i`

Comment: Maybe this can help https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/roman-numerals-converter.html?x1=&x2=999

Comment: **CM** = 1000 - 100 = 900. **MC** = 1000 + 100 = 1100. Similarly for **XC** and **IX**.

Comment: @4386427 question is incomment                                                            
      `else if(temp >=500)//999..500
   { 
    if(temp < (500 + 4 * 100))//500..899
    {     
     for(j=0;j<(temp/500);j++)
     //[499+1]=D //[500+1]=DI //[501+1]=DII //[502+1]=DII //[503+1]=DIV ??? how did I and V come in this loop?? I know that 500=D and 4=IV
                    romanNum[i++] = 'D';
    temp = temp - (temp/500) * 500; //0   
    }
    else//900..999
    { 
     romanNum[i++] = 'C'; 
     romanNum[i++] = 'M'; 
    temp = temp - (1000-100);  //0
    }
   }`

Comment: @4386427 Idk how to put the codes in new line in the comment section so sorry for the messy look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is more complicated than it needs to be (and contains a bug), so that isn't helping.

It may help to walk through an example.  Let's suppose that `num` is `2798` (it won't be since `num` maxes out at `1000` in the outermost loop, but I think this value will be more illustrative).  That will correspond to a Roman numeral of `MMDCCXCVIII`:

```
2000 = MM
 700 = DCC
  90 = XC
   8 = VIII
```

Remember that `4`s and `9`s are weird:

```
   4 = IV (1 from 5)
  40 = XL (10 from 50)
 400 = CD (100 from 500)

   9 = IX (1 from 10)
  90 = XC (10 from 100)
 900 = CM (100 from 1000)
```

So, we start by assigning `2798` to `temp`.  First we have to figure out how many thousands (`'M'`) need to be in the output:

```
if(temp>= 1000)//1000 (highest number)=M
{  
  for(j=0;j<(temp/1000);j++) //0<1 
    romanNum[i++] = 'M'; //1000=M      

  temp = temp - (temp/1000) * 1000; //0
}
```

`temp` is greater than or equal to `1000`, so we enter the `for` loop.  `temp/1000` gives us `2` (integer division gives an integer result), so we need to write two `'M'`s to `romanNum`:

```
romanNum[i++] = 'M';  // this line gets executed twice.
```

so we have

```
romanNum[0] == 'M'
romanNum[1] == 'M'
```

We then subtract that `2000` from `2798`, leaving us with `798` in `temp`.  Then we check to see if that result is greater than or equal to `500` (`'D'`):

```
else if(temp >=500)//999..500
```

It is, so then we check to see if it's less than `900`:

```
  if(temp < (500 + 4 * 100))//500..899
```

It is, so we just need to emit a single `D`:

```
    for(j=0;j<(temp/500);j++)        // this loop is actually a bit meaningless,
      romanNum[i++] = 'D';           // since temp < 1000 at this point
```

and subtract 500 from `temp`:

```
temp = temp - (temp/500) * 500;      // again, temp is < 1000, so this
                                     // could be simplified as `temp - 500`
```

If it *had* been greater than `900`, we would have had to emit a `CM` and subtract `900` from `temp`:

```
else//900..999
{ 
  romanNum[i++] = 'C'; 
  romanNum[i++] = 'M'; 
  temp = temp - (1000-100);  //0
}
```

By this point `temp` is `298` and `romanNum` is

```
romanNum[0] == 'M'
romanNum[1] == 'M'
romanNum[2] == 'D'
```

Now we have to figure out how many remaining hundreds (`'C'`) need to go into the output:

```
else if(temp>=100) //499..100
```

If `temp` is less than `400`, then we just need to emit `'C'`:

```
if(temp < (100 + 3 * 100))//100..399
{
  for(j=0;j<(temp/100);j++)
    romanNum[i++] = 'C'; //
  temp = temp - (temp/100) * 100;
}
```

In our case it is, so we write two `'C'`s to `romanNum` and subtract `200` from `temp`, leaving us with `98` and

```
romanNum[0] == 'M'
romanNum[1] == 'M'
romanNum[2] == 'D'
romanNum[3] == 'C'
romanNum[4] == 'C'
```

Otherwise, we'd have to emit a `CD` (this code emits `LD`, which is not correct):

```
else //400..499
{   
  romanNum[i++] = 'L';
  romanNum[i++] = 'D';
  temp = temp - (500-100);
}
```

You *should* be able to figure out the remainder from here.  Again, `4`s and `9`s are special cases.

For what it's worth, this code can be made *much* simpler:

```
while ( temp >= 1000 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'M';
  temp -= 1000;
}

if ( temp >= 900 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'C';
  romanNum[i++] = 'M';
  temp -= 900;
}

if ( temp >= 500 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'D';
  temp -= 500;
}

if ( temp >= 400 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'C';
  romanNum[i++] = 'D';
  temp -= 400;
}

while ( temp >= 100 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'C';
  temp -= 100;
}

if ( temp >= 90 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'X';
  romanNum[i++] = 'C';
  temp -= 90;
}

if ( temp >= 50 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'L';
  temp -= 50;
}

if ( temp >= 40 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'X';
  romanNum[i++] = 'L';
  temp -= 40;
}

while ( temp >= 10 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'X';
  temp -= 10;
}

if ( temp >= 9 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'I';
  romanNum[i++] = 'X';
  temp -= 9;
}

if ( temp >= 5 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'V';
  temp -= 5;
}

it ( temp >= 4 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'I';
  romanNum[i++] = 'V';
  temp -= 4;
}

while ( temp >= 1 )
{
  romanNum[i++] = 'I';
  temp--;
}

romanNum[i] = 0;
printf( "%s\n", romanNum );
```